# Logstash tcp input

Tags: rest, web-applications, tcp, client, logstash

I would like use the logstash tcp input plugin in mode client to connect to a web application :

```
input {
tcp {
mode => "client"
host => "194.167.200.22"
port => 80

}
}




output {

    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

It seems connect to the server, but does not receive any data.
Could tou help me?

Comment: It seems connect to the server, I sen requests to the server, then I don't receive any data.

Comment: The web aplication does not have  a restful architecture so I think that I can't use http poller input.Please could you help me ?